# Math.Ceiling Tips

Tags: c#, math, double

How would I round up the amount of `3.79` to `3.80`?

```
double number = Math.Ceiling(3.79); //Gives me 4, but I need 3.80
```

It's a simple question, but I do not know how to achieve it. Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is the expected value for `3.71`? Is it `3.7` or `3.8`?

Comment: @SonerGönül I need it to round from `3.79` to `3.80`, so the expected value is 3.8

Comment: I see but you want `3.8` for `3.71` as well? With `Round`, `3.71` will be `3.7`, not `3.8`.

Comment: For `3.71` I want `3.72`. Would that be achievable?

Comment: Not possible, it breaks all rules on `Math` class :) How do you think you can do `3.79` to `3.8` but `3.71` to `3.72` with the same way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about using [`Math.Round(double, int)` overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/75ks3aby%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) with `1` digit?

```
Math.Round(3.79, 1) // 3.8
```

Comment: Sorry, but for `3.21` the expected answer is `3.3` (*Ceiling*, not *Rounding*) not `3.2`

Comment: @DmitryBychenko You probably right but I asked it for clarification. If OP says the same, I can gladly delete it :)

Answer (score 3):

Are you looking for

```
 double number = Math.Ceiling(3.79 * 10.0) / 10.0;
```

if you want to `Round` (not find the `Ceiling`)

```
 double number = Math.Round(3.79, 1);
```

Please, note the difference:

```
  Ceiling(32.1) == 33
  Round(32.1)   == 32
```